# Can libvirtd be used without kvm?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, virt-manager

I wanted to try libvirtd with virt-manager (I wanted to test migration.) on a virtual machine (without nested virtualization support enabled, so no kvm...), and I expected it to work (and use full emulation, qemu), but instead i receive the following error:

[image: Error: No hypervisor options were found for this connection.]

The qemu package is installed. Target is Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

Is this not a supported scenario?

Comment: What have you installed on the remote machine?

Comment: I have installed the libvirt-bin and the qemu package on the remote machine. I have tried again from scratch, and could not reproduce the original issue. This time it it all just worked after installing those 2 packages. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried again from scratch, and could not reproduce the original issue. This time it it all just worked after installing the libvirt-bin and the qemu  packages on the remote machine.

So, it appears that this is indeed a supported scenario.

Answer (score 1):

When connecting to a host libvirtd can use a default path for the connection. if i remember that right :///system will be fine, whereas i.e. :///xapi would expect a specific listener.